# Recyclerview item onClick is not working while updating

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a messaging app and users can send voice messages inside the app. While a user playing a voice message, i am updating the progress bar of that message as other chat apps. While i updating the progress bar i am calling `notifyDataSetChanged` every 50ms and i noticed when i call it rapidly, my recyclerview's onclick methods are not working until stop the calling `notifyDataSetChanged`. How can i fix this problem?

Also same problem is here: [RecyclerView item onClick not working while being updated rapidly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49101115/recyclerview-item-onclick-not-working-while-being-updated-rapidly)

My viewHolder

```
public class VoiceMessageViewHolder  extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public VoiceMessageViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnVoiceMessageListener onVoiceMessageListener) {
        super(itemView);
        this.onVoiceMessageListener = onVoiceMessageListener;
        playButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.play_button);
        pauseButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.pause_button);

        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onVoiceMessageListener.onVoiceMessagePlayClick(getAdapterPosition());
            }
        });

        pauseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onVoiceMessageListener.onVoiceMessagePauseClick(getAdapterPosition());
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: pause basılıd" + System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        });

    }
```

My pause button is not working because while the voice message playing i am calling notifyDataSetChanged rapidly for progressbar.

Comment: Instead of `notifyDataSetChanged`, try using `notifyItemChanged(int position)`

Comment: Yep, it worked. If you wanna add as an answer i can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
notifyDataSetChanged
```

Try using

```
notifyItemChanged(int position)
```

**N.B:** `notifyDataSetChanged` is structural change events while `notifyItemChanged` is item change event